# Почему неправильно срабатывает условие?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$("#button").bind("click", function () { 
    var messageLenght = $("#text").length(); 
    if($('#text').val() != '' && messageLenght < 200 ){
        var message = $("#text").val(); 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "chatGetMsg.php", 
            type: "POST", 
            data: {message}, 
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function () {
                show('send');
                 del();
            }  
        });
    }
});
```

Почему не работает

```
messageLenght < 200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#text")` возвращает объект "набор элементов". Метода `length()` у этого объекта нет (есть свойство `length`, но оно возвращает количество элементов в наборе, т.е. 1 для Вашего случая). Если Вам нужно получить длину сообщения, то это делается при помощи свойства `length` объекта `String` `$("#text").val().length`

```
$("#button").bind("click", function () { 
  var message = $("#text").val(); 
  var messageLenght = message.length; 
  if(message != '' && messageLenght < 200 ){
    $.ajax({ 
      url: "chatGetMsg.php", 
     ...............
```